# Java Gson ClassCastException

Tags: java, gson

I am building a Java Servlets 3.0 REST API and using Gson to serialize some data to json.

I get this error, though:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: za.co.a.models.tables.sybase.Family cannot be cast to java.util.Map
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
at za.co.a.helpers.JsonHelper.toJson(JsonHelper.java:33)
at za.co.a.models.tables.sybase.ActiveProcesses.saveProcess(ActiveProcesses.java:57)
```

My code is as follows:

```
@Table(name = "E_FAMILY")
public class Family extends IGenericModel <Family>
{
@Id
public BigDecimal EMPLOYEE_ID;
@Id
public BigDecimal FAMILY_ID;
@Id
public BigDecimal COMPANY_ID;
public String FIRSTNAME;
public String SECONDNAME;
public String SURNAME;
public String RELATION;
public int RELATION_ID;
public String MED_DEPENDENT_YN;
public String TAX_DEPENDENT_YN;
public String GENDER;
public Date BIRTHDATE;
public String TEL_HOME;
public String TEL_WORK;
public String TEL_CELL;
public String E_MAIL;

...
}
```

The calling code:

```
public String toJson(Object obj)
{
    return gson.toJson(obj);
}
```

Family, in this case is field in a larger class, however, I'm not having any problems with any other fields or any other classes that are similar. This is the first time, in the year I've been developing this, that this error comes up. Is there a limit to the size or complexity of class Gson can serialize? Or what can I check to see what's causing the error? Or is there a way change this specific mapping, (though I don't understand why Google is trying to map this class to Map)?

Thanks
Sethmo

**Edit** Including class hierachy

IGenericModel and IGenericReadOnlyModel only contain functions. IModel has 2 members, but I've added it as part of an ExclusionStrategy so that those members don't get serialized.

```
public class IGenericModel<T> extends IGenericReadOnlyModel
{
}

public class IGenericReadOnlyModel<T> extends IModel
{
}

public class IModel
{
    protected String dbEngine;
    protected IDatabase db;
}
```

***Edit*** rest of the code

Ok, the class that holds Family is quite large and mostly full of Strings, Dates and Booleans and ints. Where Family comes in is here, the two objects are passed from the front-end and represent the old and new values (users can edit, add and delete family members in the UI, then submit those lists).

```
public abstract class IWebProcess extends IModel
{
    protected Object _OldValue;
    protected Object _NewValue;
}
```

Once submitted (as JSON from the UI), it's serialized:

```
Type familyType = new TypeToken<LinkedList<Family>>(){}.getType();
LinkedList<Family> oldFamily = gson.fromJson(oldFamilyJson, familyType);  
LinkedList<Family> newFamily = gson.fromJson(newFamilyJson, familyType);
```

Then, the concrete class is then initialized:

```
IWebProcess family = WebProcess_FamilyRequisition(oldFamily,newFamily,...,...,...)
```

then, in the constructor of WebProcess_FamilyRequisition, I call super(oldFamily, newFamily) and then in the constructor of IWebProcess:

```
this._OldValue = oldFamily
this._NewValue = newFamily
```

I do all this casting because I save the new values to the DB first, before serializing the entire WebProcess to the DB. I've made _OldValue and _NewValue Objects because this is a base class for 8 other classes that work the same and they serialize just fine.

Comment: There is no any limits with number of fields or complexity of model. Could you show also `IGenericModel` class?

Comment: I've added them in the edit. Thanks.

Comment: What is `IDatabase`, and why do you want to serialize it to json?

Comment: @Andreas, `IDatabase db` is excluded as it is pointed in comment. Model looks OK and should not be a problem. @Sethmo011, have you configured somehow `Gson` instance? It is a little bit weird that `Gson` chose `MapTypeAdapterFactory` for `POJO` class.

Comment: *"as it is pointed in comment"* What comment?

Comment: @Michal Ziober I'm not sure of the internal workings of Gson, but like I said, this is the first time I've ever come across this, in a year of using it in this library. 

I don't have any special setting I know of on gson, I initiliaze it with 

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new IModelExclusionStrategy(IModel.class))
        .serializeNulls()
        .create();`

After that, there's nothing else I do with it, settings-wise.

Comment: @Andreas, sorry, I was not precise. It should be "pointed in question after EDIT".

Comment: @Sethmo011, could you also show `POJO` class which contains `Family` as property?

Comment: @MichalZiober Ok, I'll expand in the main question, there's quite a bit to it